# Write a gcc plugin that inserts macros at the beginning of each function

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

I understand that I can use `__cyg_profile_func_enter` and `-finstrument-functions` to insert code, but is it possible to insert macros by writing a `gcc` plugin?

Is there any documentation or possibly an open source project available?

Any other tips for accomplishing this, are welcomed?

Comment: Which language, C or C++; they are distinct languages.  The C++ language has many alternatives to macros.  Also, when using GNU, prefer to use `g++` for C++ and `gcc` for C language.

Comment: Remember that most compilers are at least two pass.  The first pass is the Preprocessor which converts macros to their text and then passes the changed source to the compiler.  So you will want something that either adds macros before the Preprocessor or something that avoids the preprocessor.

Comment: Difficult to do with a `gcc` plugin. Maybe better luck with `clang`. However, you could write a [perl/python] script that does such insertion and feed the output of that to `gcc` [or `clang`]. You may want to run the source through an indenter to make the parsing easier. Ignoring `struct` definitions for the moment, after every `^{` line, add `\tENTER;\n` and before every `^}` line (and/or `return` statement), insert `\tEXIT;\n` You can then have the macros be whatever you want.

Comment: Also, initializers for arrays have `{` at the start.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler An indenter can force `int array[] =\n{\n` into `int array[] = {\n` Similar for structs. And, we can look at the preceeding line to end in `)`

Comment: Maybe a better question is WHAT do you want to achieve? Inject logging? And why macros and not function calls? And have you considered simple code generation, one that modifies your source code?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews The plugins for c++, gcc and g++ are not compatible right?So is it possible to implement this feature in a less complicated way? I've never learned anything about compiler plugins, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: @Pepijn Kramer I just want to add a log, but if I use a function like __cyg_profile_func_enter, the information I can get is limited, e.g. I can't pass __cyg_profile_func_enter a parameter to get information outside of this function.

Comment: My next question would be is why would you want to do that? Is it for debugging? Because adding logging for debugging is probably going to change the behavior of your code which might mask the bug. Does your code have unit tests?

Comment: @Coloda Thomas, Pepijn, and I are all pretty much saying the same thing. (e.g.) The script I proposed _is_ a code generator. You add the steps via the `Makefile`. Or, just have the script (You can write a 20-30 line C program instead of a script), be named (e.g.) `xcc` and do `CC = xcc` in the makefile and have the script/program call the indenter, add the macros/functions and feed the output to `gcc`. If you parse the simplified input, you can extract whatever info you want (e.g. function parameters, return values).

Comment: What you are looking for is called "instrumentation" of code. I don't know gcc well but it seems it has some instrumentation options : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.1.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html

Comment: To instrument your code, you may want to add it permanently with macros that do `printf` and add the debug code if `-DDEBUG` (e.g.) is given. Here are some examples: [couldn't find out how to solve this algorithm problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74103462/5382650) and [Descending Priority Queue using Linked List without taking Priority as input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65451748/5382650) To do tracing that minimizes overhead, consider an "event" queue/ring buffer: [How to synchronize multiple processes in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69817970/5382650)

Comment: I know that it is possible to automate the process of adding code to each function by using a script, but it seems to me that this is not easy to do, and with a complex C++ project trying to accurately find the enter and exiter of each function doesn't seem to be something that can be accomplished with a few dozen lines of script.

Comment: I was just wondering if it's possible to implement code instrumentation by writing a compiler plugin. i just took over a big obsolete project at my company, and for some reason it's not possible to debug it with gdb, the code looks like a pain in the ass, so i thought the easiest way to know the code call relationships would be the log.Regarding the use of __cyg_profile_func_enter to code instrumentation I've already implemented it, just wondering if I can insert macros to do something more flexible.